# How to hide class in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several instances of a class in a div. I know the id of the div. I can't get it to work.

```
$('#ContactPersonChildListDiv').children().filter('.lrml').hide()
```

This doesn't work.
So I need to hide all the children of the div with `id='ContactPersonChildListDiv'`, that belong to the class `lrml`.

Comment: Provide the HTML that will help to give you an answer.

Comment: What about `$('#ContactPersonChildListDiv .lrml').hide()` Selects all classes `lrml` within `#ContactPersonChildListDiv`

Comment: @Bondye post your solution as answer.

Comment: Why don't you just use css for this?

Comment: Works fine for me (as expected): http://jsfiddle.net/fh6xdtd9/ . I hope you don't actually have a div with the `id` "#ContactPersonChildListDiv" (including the "#"). You obviously have a typo or misunderstanding somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide all the children with that class use `>` selector:

```
$('#ContactPersonChildListDiv > .lrml').hide();
```

If you want to hide all *descendants* with that class use:

```
$('#ContactPersonChildListDiv .lrml').hide();
```

---

Selecting elements with jQuery is very close (in this case, the same) like you select them with [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html):

> `E F` Matches any F element that is a descendant of an E element. Descendant selectors
>
> `E > F`   Matches any F element that is a child of an element E.

Answer (score 0):

What's your HTML code?

You posted that the id of div is

```
id='#ContactPersonChildListDiv'
```

Be sure that # doesn't be in this id, like

```
<div id='ContactPersonChildListDiv'>
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, you didn't provide any HTML but this may help you.
Try this:

```
$('#ContactPersonChildListDiv').find('.lrml').hide();
```

Youl could also do this way:

```
$('#ContactPersonChildListDiv .lrml').hide();
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
$('#ContactPersonChildListDiv').children('.lrml').hide();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lekb576r/)

Answer (score -2):

The HTML:

```
<div id='ContactPersonChildListDiv'>
        <div class='aaa'>AAA</div>
        <div class='lrml'>LRML</div>
        <div class='bbb'>BBB</div>
    </div>

    <input type='button' onclick='hideSomeClass()'>
```

AND JS:

```
function hideSomeClass(){
            var pdiv=document.getElementById('ContactPersonChildListDiv');
            var divs=pdiv.children;
            for (var i = divs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if(divs[i].className=='lrml'){
                    divs[i].style.display='none';
                }
            };
        }
```